# CC3100 p2p application, 256 type name is not allowed

Tags: c++, c

I'm working on a p2p sample application of texas instrument, working with cc3100 and MSP430ff5529.
So we are speaking about a connection between android and the cc3100.

to know, CLI is just to write on the console

Here is my problem, after some manipulation the program enters in this function LOOP_FOREVER

```
/* Stop the CC3100 device */
retVal = sl_Stop(SL_STOP_TIMEOUT);
if(retVal < 0)
    LOOP_FOREVER();
```

LOOP_FOREVER is this function

```
#define LOOP_FOREVER() \
            {\
                while(1); \
            }
```

so it is blocked.
I changed with a new function, which should do something if an event appears(like disconnect or something like this), I'm not sure it works because I can't build it.
This is how i modified the program

```
CLI_Write(" stop device \n\r");
  /* Stop the CC3100 device */
    retVal = sl_Stop(SL_STOP_TIMEOUT);
    if(retVal < 0) function1(&SlWlanEvent_t);
    //  LOOP_FOREVER();
    return 0;
```

this is the function

```
void function1(void* handle)
{SlWlanEvent_t* oref=(SlWlanEvent_t*) handle;
    CLI_Write(" mia funzione \n\r");
    _u32 EventParam = oref->Event;
    while(oref->Event == EventParam);}
```

and this is the structure I call

```
typedef struct
{
   _u32     Event;
   SlWlanEventData_u        EventData;
} SlWlanEvent_t;
```

The problem is when I call the function.

## 256 type name is not allowed   main.c  /p2p    line 538    C/C++ Problem

I tryed to change it:

```
if(retVal < 0) function1(&SlWlanEvent_t);

if(retVal < 0) function1(SlWlanEvent_t);

if(retVal < 0) function1(*SlWlanEvent_t);
```

but noone of this works, can you help me fix this?
I need to modify my program more than this but I'm not a genius of programmation so I go step by step.

Thank you

Luca